# change size of plots in htmltools::taglist R markdown

Tags: r, r-plotly, r-leaflet, htmltools

I am trying to use a loop in Rmarkdown that prints a leaflet map and plotly graph side by side (the loop iterates through vegetation types). I am having trouble getting the side-by-side to have the height and width I desire.

**In the joint plot I would like to have the leaflet and plotly with two different sizes. Any suggestions?**

Both chunks use the following heading:
{r, echo=F, warning=F, message=F, fig.height=12, fig.width=20)

The markdown header is such:

```
title: "test"        
date: "February 7, 2021"       
output:         
  html_document:       
    toc: true         
    toc_float:         
      collapsed: false         
  smooth_scroll: false       
latex_engine: xelatex        
header-includes:        
 - \usepackage{fontspec}       
 - \setmainfont{Georgia}       
fig.width: 16       
fig.height: 12
```

```
  
library(leaflet)
library(plotly)
library(leafsync)
library(htmltools)

  leaflet( ) %>%     
        addTiles(options = tileOptions(noWrap = TRUE)) %>% 
        
        fitBounds(lng1 = 120, lat1 = -12, lng2 = 130, lat2 = -42) %>% 
        addProviderTiles(providers$Esri.WorldImagery, group = "Esri World Imagery")
```

```
maps <- lapply(c(1,2),function(x){
  
  print(x)

 p = leaflet( ) %>%     # width=500, height=500
        addTiles(options = tileOptions(noWrap = TRUE)) %>% 
        
        fitBounds(lng1 = 120, lat1 = -12, lng2 = 130, lat2 = -42) %>% 
        addProviderTiles(providers$Esri.WorldImagery, group = "Esri World Imagery") 
  
  
  p2 <- plot_ly() %>% layout(title = x)
  
          p2 <- plotly::add_trace(p2, x = c(1, 2, 3), y = c(4, 3, 2), mode='lines')
          
          p2 <- plotly::add_trace(p2, x = c(20, 30, 40), y = c(30, 40, 50), xaxis='x2', yaxis='y2', mode='lines')
          
              
    # inset      
  p2 <- plotly::layout(p2,
            xaxis2 = list(domain = c(0.7, 0.95), anchor='y2'),
            yaxis2 = list(domain = c(0.7, 0.95), anchor='x2'))
      
  leafsync::latticeview(p,p2)
  
 
  
})

htmltools::tagList(maps )
```

Here's a partial screen grab (just shows that the standalone leaflet chunk is creating a map per the height and width in the header. The joint leaflet-plotly does not reflect the height-width, and is coming out to small.)

**In the joint plot I would like to have the leaflet and plotly with two different sizes. Any suggestions?**

[image]

Comment: Did you get an answer? If not, may be your question is too long. If you can bring its size down it may get some answers. I am posting a new question that is similar but shorter.